# User Choice for an RPS game

Tags: javascript, dom-events

**Problem:** When I click either rock, paper, or scissors, I want to return a value for each choice. I then want the  value choice from USER_CHOICE and value choice from COMPUTER_CHOICE to be compared to determine who wins.

COMPUTER_CHOICE works, but the comparison functions aren't or the USER_CHOICE function isn't returning a value. I may have over-complicated such an easy game, and I had both working before, but forgot to git tag it.

**Desired Result:** When the user clicks rock, paper, or scissors, I want it to return a value. I then want the values from USER_CHOICE and COMPUTER_CHOICE to be compared so that a winner can be determined.

JSBIN: http://jsbin.com/rukomugaze/edit?html,js,output

JavaScript:

```
window.onload = function() {

var CHOICE_ROCK = document.querySelector('#rock'),
  CHOICE_PAPER = document.querySelector('#paper'),
  CHOICE_SCISSORS = document.querySelector('#scissors'),
  WINNER_TXT = document.querySelector('#winner'),
  BUTTONS = document.querySelectorAll('input'),
  COMP_TXT = document.querySelector('#compChoice');


CHOICE_ROCK.addEventListener('click', USER_CHOICE, false);
CHOICE_PAPER.addEventListener('click', USER_CHOICE, false);
CHOICE_SCISSORS.addEventListener('click', USER_CHOICE, false);



// Return user choice value;
function USER_CHOICE(e) {
  var el = e.target;
  if (el === CHOICE_ROCK) {
    ROCK();
    COMP_TXT.innerHTML = COMPUTER_CHOICE() + ' is the computers choice!';
    console.log('I am rock');
    return 'rock';
  } else if (el === CHOICE_PAPER) {
    COMP_TXT.innerHTML = COMPUTER_CHOICE() + ' is the computers choice!';
    console.log('I am paper');
    return 'paper';
  } else if (el === CHOICE_SCISSORS) {
    COMP_TXT.innerHTML = COMPUTER_CHOICE() + ' is the computers choice!';
    console.log('I am scissors');
    return 'scissors';
  }
  e.stopPropagation();
}
// Return value of computer choice
function COMPUTER_CHOICE() {
  var num = Math.floor(Math.random() * 3) + 1;
  var choice = '';
  if (num === 1) {
    choice = 'rock';
  } else if (num === 2) {
    choice = 'paper';
  } else {
    choice = 'scissors';
  }
  return choice;
}

// function TIE(USER_CHOICE, COMPUTER_CHOICE) {
//   if (USER_CHOICE === COMPUTER_CHOICE) {
//     WINNER_TXT.innerHTML = 'ITS A TIE!';
//   }
// }


// Break up into functions
// compare values of user choice and computer chocie
function ROCK(COMPUTER_CHOICE) {
  if (USER_CHOICE === CHOICE_ROCK && COMPUTER_CHOICE === 'scissors') {
    WINNER_TXT.innerHTML = 'ROCK WINS!';
  } else if (USER_CHOICE === CHOICE_ROCK && COMPUTER_CHOICE === 'paper') {
    WINNER_TXT.innerHTML = 'PAPER WINS!';
  }
}

function PAPER(USER_CHOICE, COMPUTER_CHOICE) {
  //Paper
  if (USER_CHOICE === CHOICE_PAPER && COMPUTER_CHOICE === 'rock') {
    WINNER_TXT.innerHTML = 'PAPER WINS!';
  } else if (USER_CHOICE === CHOICE_PAPER && COMPUTER_CHOICE === 'scissors') {
    WINNER_TXT.innerHTML = 'PAPER WINS!';
  }
}

function SCISSORS(USER_CHOICE, COMPUTER_CHOICE) {
  //scissors
  if (USER_CHOICE === CHOICE_SCISSORS && COMPUTER_CHOICE === 'paper') {
    WINNER_TXT.innerHTML = 'SCISSORS WINS!';
  } else if (USER_CHOICE === CHOICE_SCISSORS && COMPUTER_CHOICE === 'rock') {
    WINNER_TXT.innerHTML = 'ROCK WINS!';
  }
}
};
```

HTML:

```
<!doctype html>
<html class="no-js" lang="">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="ie=edge">
        <title></title>
        <meta name="description" content="">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

        <link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="apple-touch-icon.png">
        <!-- Place favicon.ico in the root directory -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.rawgit.com/twbs/bootstrap/v4-dev/dist/css/bootstrap.css" integrity="sha384-XXXXXXXX" crossorigin="anonymous">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css">
        <script src="js/vendor/modernizr-2.8.3.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <!--[if lt IE 8]>
            <p class="browserupgrade">You are using an <strong>outdated</strong> browser. Please <a href="http://browsehappy.com/">upgrade your browser</a> to improve your experience.</p>
        <![endif]-->
        <div class="container">
          <div class="header"><h1>ROCK, PAPER, OR SCISSORS!</h1></div>
          <div><span>Choose wisely...</span></div>
          <div><span id="winner">Winner text</span></div>
          <div><span id="compChoice">Winner text</span></div>
          <div class="inner-container">
            <div class="row">
              <div class='items'>
                <img class="rps" src="https://cdn0.iconfinder.com/data/icons/rock-paper-scissors-emoji/792/rock-paper-scissors-emoji-cartoon-027-128.png" width="200" height="300">
                  <div><input type="submit" value="Rock" id="rock"></div>
              </div>
              <div class='items'>
                <img class="rps" src="https://cdn0.iconfinder.com/data/icons/rock-paper-scissors-emoji/792/rock-paper-scissors-emoji-cartoon-019-256.png" width="200" height="300">
                  <div><input type="submit" value="Paper" id="paper"></div>
              </div>
              <div class='items'>
                <img class="rps" src="https://cdn0.iconfinder.com/data/icons/rock-paper-scissors-emoji/792/rock-paper-scissors-emoji-cartoon-014-512.png" width="200" height="300">
                  <div><input type="submit" value="Scissors" id="scissors"></div>
              </div>
              </div>
          </div>
          <div class="footer">
            <span>&copy; Zack 2016</span>
          </div>
        </div>






        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script>window.jQuery || document.write('<script src="js/vendor/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"><\/script>')</script>
        <script src="js/plugins.js"></script>
        <script src="js/main.js"></script>

        <!-- Google Analytics: change UA-XXXXX-X to be your site's ID. -->
        <script>
            (function(b,o,i,l,e,r){b.GoogleAnalyticsObject=l;b[l]||(b[l]=
            function(){(b[l].q=b[l].q||[]).push(arguments)});b[l].l=+new Date;
            e=o.createElement(i);r=o.getElementsByTagName(i)[0];
            e.src='https://www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js';
            r.parentNode.insertBefore(e,r)}(window,document,'script','ga'));
            ga('create','UA-XXXXX-X','auto');ga('send','pageview');
        </script>
      <script src="rps.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: What errors do you get in the console? I tried your code in [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mtqukygh/) and it works as expected, so there must be something else that is wrong.

Comment: You need to store the returns of COMPUTER_CHOICE() and USER_CHOICE() in a variable. And you are not calling your ROCK,... function

Comment: @Daniel B. Yeah the computer choice part works, but if you look at the functions ROCK, PAPER, and SCISSORS. I want them to compare the USER choice when clicked, and the computer choice. The text that says 'winner text' should be changing to things like: 'ROCK WINS' or 'PAPER WINS!' etc.

Comment: Well, you never call the `ROCK` function, thus nothing will happen. Are you asking how to call the compare functions after the buttons have been clicked?

Comment: @Daniel B, I have tried calling ROCK, but still getting the same results. Unless I am calling it wrong?

Comment: In that case, the code you've included is not your current code, because you don't call `ROCK()` anywhere in that code snippet.

Comment: @Danield B. Updated it calling ROCK(); within the USER_CHOICE function.

Comment: @Daniel B: I appreciate your help, but I did a bit more thinking, and got the results I wanted. Cheers mate!

Comment: Glad you got it sorted. I just posted an answer with some stuff that might be helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have multiple errors in your code that stops it from working the way you want.

First of all, you're calling the corresponding event handler incorrectly by only calling `ROCK()` without any arguments.

Instead of returning something from the event listener function, you can simply call the event handler with the user choice and the computer choice, as below.

```
if (el === CHOICE_ROCK) {
    COMP_TXT.innerHTML = computerChoice + ' is the computers choice!';
    console.log('I am rock');
    ROCK("rock", computerChoice);
}
```

and similarly for the other two choices.

Further down in your code, you are comparing a string to an element, instead of the value of the element. In your case, you have mixed casing so it would be easier to use the `element.id` instead of the value.

```
function ROCK(USER_CHOICE, COMPUTER_CHOICE) {
    console.log("Inside rock function");
    //Note that CHOICE_ROCK is an element, and you try to compare it to a string
    //Instead, look at the elements id and use that to compare
    if (USER_CHOICE === CHOICE_ROCK.id && COMPUTER_CHOICE === 'scissors') {
        console.log("rock wins");
        WINNER_TXT.innerHTML = 'ROCK WINS!';
    } else if (USER_CHOICE === CHOICE_ROCK.id && COMPUTER_CHOICE === 'paper') {
        console.log("PAPER wins");
        WINNER_TXT.innerHTML = 'PAPER WINS!';
        console.log(WINNER_TXT)
    }
}
```

I fixed the code so it works when the user clicks the *rock* button, and you can try it yourself in [this JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/r6kf4vL7/). It should be easy for you to fix the rest of the code if you look at the changes.

Comment: DOH! I always forget to call my functions without the args. One thing I need to start getting in the habit of not forgetting. Your changes make total sense now that I see the function being passed args. Wow, I didn't even know something like    element.id    existed. I did figure out another way to get my results too, thats what i love about languages, many solutions to one problem. I appreciate all your help today, and I definitely learned some new things from you! cheers!

Comment: Glad I could help. I think you should look at what `document.querySelector('#rock')` returns, as it's not what you initially thought. It selects and returns an element, or if using a class identifier, an array of elements.

Comment: Would getElementByID return differently? I've read about there being different ways to select elements, but I think I may have missed the part on what they return when doing so.

Comment: No, as the function name suggests it *gets* the *element* from the *id*. It will thus return a reference to the matching element. You can then access the elements properites using `element.id`, `element.style` and so on. Get the habit of checking up functions on [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementById) as they explain how they work.

Comment: Yeah I do check up on functions. Just been a while since I've read about getters like ELEMNTBYID and QUERYSELECTOR. Thanks man cheers!